# Wildfly 16 - problem with setting up rewrite rules inside WAR file

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-16

This is my first contact with Wildfly/JBoss and JAVA web technology. I want to write this upfront to avoid confusion and to indicate I'm a newbie :)

I'm trying to setup rewrite rules for a website that is hosted on WildFly 16 server.
I have a Linux machine that has Apache installed and configured as a reverse-proxy.
On the same machine is a docker that runs Wildfly.
I have access to WAR file and I try to do all the modifications there (I don't have access to project files)

Part of the website is build using react and it needs those 3 rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

I've checked those rules on Apache with PHP (in htaccess file) and they work perfectly.

My problem is I can't get RewriteRules to work on Wildfly.

According to the docs (https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html) I need to add:

```
<valve>
   <class-name>"org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve"</class-name>
</valve>
```

to `jboss-web.xml`. I did that, but in WAR wile, so now the `WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml` file has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
    <valve>
        <class-name>"org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve"</class-name>
    </valve>
    <context-root>/TestYourSkills</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

then (also according to the docs) I've added `rewrite.properties` file in WEB-INF folder with the following content:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [L]
```

but I can't get that to work. I've tried adding even simpler rules, but all my attempts failed.

Am I doing something wrong?
Maybe I need to enable something else or add additional JAR files to `WEB-INF\lib`?
I'm totally new to WildFly, but I spend almost two days trying different things and searching over the net.

Any advice is more than welcome.

Comment: WildFly does not use Tomcat as the servlet container. The link to the documentation you reference is quite old. This may be helpful http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/configuring-predicates-and-exchange-with-undertow.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thank you for the link. Any idea how to convert that htaccess to undertow? As I wrote I have only WAR file, so can't do that via code.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it in the WAR or not TBH. I think you need to configure the server itself.